# Populate datatables with AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I am working on datatables. I need to populate my data table with AJAX call BUT I am unable to do so.
Here is my AJAX call:

```
$('#call_analysis_basic_table').DataTable ({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "getBasicCallAnalysisData.json",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "ANUMBER" },
        { "data": "BNUMBER" },
        { "data": "DATETIME" },
        { "data": "DURATION" },
        { "data": "IMEI" },
        { "data": "IMSI" },
        { "data": "CELL ID" },
        { "data": "OPR ID" },
        { "data": "MSC ID" },
        { "data": "FILE ID" }
    ]
});
```

Datatable HTML code:

```
<table id="call_analysis_basic_table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead style="background-color:#4d7496;color:#fff;">
        <tr>
            <th>aNumber</th>
            <th>bNumber</th>
            <th>datetime</th>
            <th>duration</th>
            <th>imei</th>
            <th>imsi</th>
            <th>cellID</th>
            <th>oprid</th>
            <th>msc_id</th>
            <th>file_id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Expected JSON Response :

```
{
    "result": [
        [
            "3028540439",
            "3222027076",
            "2017-06-01 07:58:50.0",
            "984",
            "45113694289302",
            "45113694289302",
            "34546789606976",
            "410-07-511-19601",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1"
        ],
        [
            "3028540439",
            "3224712938",
            "2017-05-11 06:07:21.0",
            "4",
            "12962129644848",
            "12962129644848",
            "34469708781694",
            "410-06-651-30213",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1"
        ]
    ],
    "success": true,
    "error": "no error"
}
```

After making this call, The response from server comes but response doesn't populate into datatable. It Shows me this error

> DataTables warning: table id=call_analysis_basic_table - no error

Any hint, How can I populate this JSON response to my datatable?

Comment: Normally in my response JSON objects I have keys with the data, are you sure it can be populated like this, relying only on the order of the element so it can be binded? And not having something like : { "ANUMBER": "3028540439", "BNUMBER": "3222027076",  // and so on }

Comment: I need to populate datatable with this response. To change this, Its a very big headache :(

Comment: check my answer below and you only need the `result` key from the response Object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the `"columns"` property here as you are loading the datatable from an array only not from a proper JSON response. Also you have 10 columns in the table but 11 items in each array which will not work. The number of items in array should be same as columns in the table if you are using array to populate the table.
Try with the below code -

```
$('#call_analysis_basic_table').DataTable ({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "getBasicCallAnalysisData.json",
        "type": "POST"
    }
});
```

Also your datasource array should be like below -

```
{
    "result": [
        [
            "3028540439",
            "3222027076",
            "2017-06-01 07:58:50.0",
            "984",
            "45113694289302",
            "45113694289302",
            "34546789606976",
            "410-07-511-19601",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1"
        ],
        [
            "3028540439",
            "3224712938",
            "2017-05-11 06:07:21.0",
            "4",
            "12962129644848",
            "12962129644848",
            "34469708781694",
            "410-06-651-30213",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1" //extra value is here 
        ]
    ]
}
```

and you can add a table footer in your HTML

```
<table id="call_analysis_basic_table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead style="background-color:#4d7496;color:#fff;">
        <tr>
            <th>aNumber</th>
            <th>bNumber</th>
            <th>datetime</th>
            <th>duration</th>
            <th>imei</th>
            <th>imsi</th>
            <th>cellID</th>
            <th>oprid</th>
            <th>msc_id</th>
            <th>file_id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot style="background-color:#4d7496;color:#fff;">
        <tr>
            <th>aNumber</th>
            <th>bNumber</th>
            <th>datetime</th>
            <th>duration</th>
            <th>imei</th>
            <th>imsi</th>
            <th>cellID</th>
            <th>oprid</th>
            <th>msc_id</th>
            <th>file_id</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

check this link for more reference 
[Jquery datatable ajax with array](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html)

Comment: Why should I change my JSON response ?

Comment: because its not a JSON response ... you don't have a key value pair in the `result`.It's an simple array.I provided the link for using array with datatable above.

Comment: Dear, I cant change my response here.

Comment: Ok did you try with the code I provided and the same response you received earlier?